# .htaccess require valid-user on Remote server, not local

Tags: apache, .htaccess

This is my .htacess file.  I'm trying to figure out how to to require a valid user with username/password only on the remote server, not on my local dev environment.  Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
require valid-user
AuthUserFile "/home/username/.htpasswds/public_html/passwd"
```

Comment: Just to make things extra fun, the remote server is using Apache 2.4 and the local server is using Apache 2.2

Comment: Use 2 different .htaccess files. 2.4 has different directives that aren't supported such as Satisfy any.

Comment: @PanamaJack How do I use 2 different .htaccess files?  I don't want to have to keep switching back and forth on remote / local.

Comment: This doesn't directly solve the problem I posted, but I got this to work in Mamp Pro. In Hosts > Extended > I checked None in the AllowOverride field and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

For those happening to stumble upon this old question, I use the following `.htaccess` logic in scenarios where I have one codebase for `localhost`, production, and a preview/staging environment, and only want to password-protect the latter:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'preview.example.com'">
  AuthName "Preview Example"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthUserFile /example-path/.htpasswd
  Require valid-user
</If>
```